# Calling Python from R with reticulate package

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I want to execute a Python script in R. I've installed reticulate and tested that a Python version has correctly initialized in my R session.

```
py_config()
```

returns the following

```
python:         C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 15:18:16) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.1
```

Now, when I call the Python script

```
py_run_file("PythonScript.py")
```

I hit the following error in R

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I understand that I need to install requests package but how do I make this in the specific Python version I've initialized?

Comment: what platform/OS are you working on? IOS? unix?

Comment: If you look under `~/AppData/Local/r-miniconda` for the `conda` executable, can you then run `conda install requests`? I don't have that distro of miniconda here so I cannot test it easily, but that seems like one reasonable approach. Another (perhaps more of a "best practice") would be to use a virtual environment and make sure the packages you need are installed and maintained.

Comment: @Onyambu Windows, since I think ``C:/...`` is exclusive to Windows. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: sorry my bad. I should have noticed that!! You are right

Comment: I suggest that you need to read https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html, where they discuss (*with examples*) how to deal with python packages when using `reticulate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function that collects the missing packages and installs them:

```
run_python_file <- function(python_file){
    a = try(reticulate::py_run_file(python_file),silent=TRUE)
    if(inherits(a,"try-error")& grepl("ModuleNotFoundError",a)){
        system(sprintf("python -m pip install %s",gsub(".* |\\W","",c(a))))
        run_python_file(python_file)
      }
    else a
   }
run_python_file("PythonScript.py")
```

Comment: Seems futureproof, will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python module `requests` before.

If you have installed python, you should have installed pip with it.
You can install the module by running  `pip install requests` in command line.